# error during compile nginx on windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows, nginx, compilation

I want to compile nginx on windows and every time I try, I get this error message:
[image]

how can I solve it? please help me to solve that.

Comment: Why you want to compile it, and why you want nginx on windows?

Comment: I want to add module on it and I need it on windows

Comment: I successfully built nginx for 32-bit Windows with Visual Studio 2013, cl version 18.00.21005.1, after slightly patching objs/Makefile. Did not encounter iob_func error described above.